# Understanding export_tflite_ssd_graph.py

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

[Here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193) is tutorial about converting Mobilenet+SSD to tflite at some point they use [export_tflite_ssd_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py), as I understand this custom script is used to support `tf.image.non_max_suppression` operation.

```
export CONFIG_FILE=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/pipeline.config
export CHECKPOINT_PATH=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train/model.ckpt-2000
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/tflite

python object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \
--pipeline_config_path=$CONFIG_FILE \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix=$CHECKPOINT_PATH \
--output_directory=$OUTPUT_DIR \
--add_postprocessing_op=true
```

But I wonder what is `pipeline.config` and how to create it if I use custom model(for example [FaceBoxes](https://github.com/TropComplique/FaceBoxes-tensorflow)) that use `tf.image.non_max_suppression` operation?

Answer (score 2):

The main objective of `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` is to export the training checkpoint files into a frozen graph that you can later use for transfer learning or for straight inference (because they contain the model structure info as well as the trained weights info). In fact, all the models listed in **[model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)** are the frozen graph generated this way.

As for the `tf.image.non_max_suppression`, `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` is not used to 'support' it but if `--add_postprocessing_op` is set `true` there will be another custom op node added to the frozen graph, this custom node will have the functionality similar to op `tf.image.non_max_suppression`. See reference [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/dadc4a625d273f995f8297968859c252147029ee/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py#L39).

Finally the `pipeline.config` file  directly corresponds to a config file in the you use for training (`--pipeline_config_path`), it is a copy of it  but often with a modified score threshold (See description [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/r1.12.0/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) about `pipeline.config`.), so you will have to create it before the training if you use a custom model. And to create a custom config file, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) is the official tutorial.

Comment: `add_postprocessing_op` is supported tflite op or what is purpose of doing this?